queue animation with custom population
I made a simple animation with a source, queue, delay and a sink.
I made my own agent called "Part" to simulate the production.
In a node I showed how many parts are in the queue.
In the next step I made two populations of my "Part": partsmall and partmedium
I am using them so I can simulate different delay times for each population.
But when I change in source the default population to custom population the animation in the node does not work any more.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
THX
Thomas
enter image description here

You need to define your own animation once you create a custom agent type. Drag in a rectangle into the agent type and make sure to click the "Show presentation" button in the agent population that the Source creates into.
(Strongly suggest you do the step-by-step tutorials first as they cover stuff like this in depth)

THX Benjamin for the information. I had a circle in the agent, but I didn't pressed the button "show presentation".
